# When clicking back or home button, app goes back to activity's parent but onStart() isn't always called

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have activity A.
When I go to settings from the Nav Drawer, I change some settings and back (via the back or home), most of the times the onStart() in activity A gets called.

This is where I load the shared Prefs.

However, sometimes onStart() doesn't get called and it goes directly to onResume(). Once this happens once, repeating this user interaction will always return to onResume() and not call onStart() of Activity A.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to do that in `onResume` not `onStart` because if application paused or restarted or created `onResume` will called but `onStart` is fired after and `onRestart` or `onCreate`